# Пожалуйста, проверьте, все ли запятые в моем сочинении стоят на своих местах. Если нет, то поправьте, я не обижусь!

Tags: орфография, семантика

Я считаю, что внутренне состояние героя, от лица которого ведется повествование из рассказа «Скрипка» очень переменчивое. Если, сначала ему было скучно, то потом мальчик восторженно, удивленно слушал игру скрипки.
Сначала, когда мама привела его в консерваторию, первичное состояние героя было: равнодушие, незаинтересованность. Изначально, ему было все равно, куда его ведут: он надел кеды вместо ботинок, не стал чистить свой пиджак. Мальчику было все безразлично: куда ему указали, туда он с мамой и сел. Ему не важно, что происходило на сцене. Его внимание ничего не зацепляло: «выходили люди, поблескивали очками и водили смычками». Он воспринимал все равнодушно и беспристрастно. Но потом, когда вышла скрипачка, его состояние резко сменилось. Автор подчеркивает это повтором: «заиграла на скрипке, заиграла на узкой скрипке». Мальчик чувствовал себя очень удивленно, он не понимал, как из такой узкой скрипки, выходили красивые звуки. Он стал внимательно слушать музыку. Герой был столь потрясен красивой игрой, что даже не захотел съесть мороженное: «-по мороженному? Нет-нет - я сказал, спасибо».
Вот почему чувства мальчика во время рассказа сильно менялись.

А это собственно произведение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Общее впечатление (для тех, кто не обижается). Повторы (сначала, изначально), речевые штампы, мало эмоций, сюжет тянется как прямая линия, напоминая отчет о рассказе, а не впечатление читателя. Но вот интересно, а вам понравились стихи? Вера Полозкова вроде бы интересная поэтесса со своим стилем. Как бы вы пересказали их другу, что главное в них поразило? Или ничего не поразило? Такой рассказ, наверное, сильно отличался бы от сочинения. Но надо знать еще общий уровень учащихся, возможно, у меня завышенные ожидания, а на самом деле сочинение отличное.

Comment: И еще хорошее правило по принципу "Пиши, сокращай", и это относится к каждому предложению и к каждому абзацу. Мы любим растягивать действие, поэтому текст при сокращении смотрится лучше. Ну а потом можно добавить что-нибудь красивое, увеличив объем, если   фрагмент не раскрыт в полной мере. Будьте  "художественным конструктором" текста, это даже интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант:

Из рассказа  «Девушка и скрипка»  мы узнаем, как музыка может изменить внутреннее состояние героя. Если сначала  было скучно и неинтересно, то потом мальчик восторженно и удивленно слушал  скрипичную игру.

Равнодушие,  безразличие, незаинтересованность – таково было  настроение.  И было все равно, куда его ведут: вот мама велела надеть ботинки вместо кед, почистила пиджак.  Куда ему указали «тетеньки», туда он и сел.

Наконец  начался концерт, что-то  происходило на сцене, но ничего не «зацепляло»: выходили люди, водили смычками, а потом уходили. Он же воспринимал все равнодушно и беспристрастно.

Но когда вышла неулыбчивая девушка и «заиграла на скрипке, заиграла на узкой скрипке», мальчик был неожиданно потрясен.  Он замер и забыл обо всем на свете.  С чем сравнить это чувство? Как будто бы «сдал экзамен или «долетел до орбиты». Как будто самая малость осталась до разгадки тайны! И публика тоже не дышала, а сквозь тонкое запястье девушки проступало счастье…

Они вышли из зала… «По мороженому?» – спросила мама.  Нет, конечно же, нет! Потому что он как будто еще там, в зале, и слышит эту чудесную музыку.

P.S.  **Чтобы научиться писать, надо писать каждый день.** Примерно так же, как эта девушка играет на скрипке. Тогда будет слушаться перо,  а  мысли не будут путаться  со словами.  Каждый урок словесности должен начинаться  **с небольшого сочинения**, тогда мы научимся писать.

Уже двести лет прошло со времен Пушкина, а мы мало чему научились в части освоения художественного литературного пространства. Мы в своей письменной речи **ходим как по ниточке** – образ за образом, словечко за словечком. Нет естественности и раскованности, нет простора и пространства! Оно есть везде – в жизни, в науке, в искусстве,  но только не в литературе.  Там мы освоили разные стили – научный, книжный, деловой, но только не художественный.(Это мое личное мнение.)

Comment: Вздор и чепуха.

Comment: Это вы о чем? О девушке, о музыке или о смысле жизни?

Answer (score 1):

Есть лишние запятые (например, «если» и «изначально» — не вводные слова и не отделяются запятыми), а что касается смысла, то с ним дело обстоит ещё хуже. Прежде всего, это не просто рассказ, а рассказ в стихах. То есть стихотворение.

Ещё одна запятая, которую не было причин ставить: «как из такой узкой скрипки(,) выходили красивые звуки». А вот здесь как раз нужна запятая, закрывающая придаточную часть сложноподчинённого предложения: «...внутренне состояние героя, от лица которого ведется повествование из рассказа «Скрипка»(**,**) очень переменчивое», — и «в рассказе», а не «из рассказа». (Хотя это и в грамотном написании будет неверно.)

И ещё: «мороженое» пишется так, как написано у меня, через одну Н.

По смыслу: внимание мальчика (а оно было, и наблюдение насчёт «очков» на это указывает) привлекло то, что скрипачка не улыбнулась зрителям перед тем, как начать играть, — то ли потому, что была слишком взволнована, то ли сознательно посчитала, что это лишнее: я выхожу показывать музыку, а не себя! Это помогло маленькому герою отождествиться с исполнительницей: значит, вот к этой музыке, которую я сейчас слышу, она относится очень серьёзно! И он незаметно для себя начал стараться воспринимать эту музыку так, как воспринимает её она. Так что взволнован, — настолько, что не захотел мороженого! — он был не просто «игрой», а МУЗЫКОЙ. А также тем, что получил опыт соприкосновения с другой личностью (строго говоря, даже двумя личностями: исполнителя и автора музыки).

Comment: А что по смыслу? какие ошибки??

Comment: По смыслу стихов или сочинения? Кстати, «сначала» тоже не отделяется запятой.

Comment: По смысслу сочинения) Пожааалуйста

Comment: Я отделил "сначала" запятой,  потому что после него сразу идет слово "когда"

Comment: Попробую. Начну с того, что «состояние очень переменчивое» означает, собственно говоря, что состояние меняется, во-1-х, БЫСТРО, во-2-х, в разных, если можно так выразиться, направлениях, в-3-х, БЕСПРИЧИННО. А главный герой реагирует вполне адекватно: его берут туда, где он ещё никогда не был, настраивают его на праздничный лад («какие кеды? надень ботинки»), он, естественно, ожидает каких-то чудес, но до поры до времени ничего удивительного не происходит: выходят люди, водят смычками и уходят. Причём маленький герой наблюдателен: он заметил, что люди «поблёскивали очками».

Comment: «Я отделил "сначала" запятой, потому что после него сразу идет слово "когда"» — ну да, в данном случае запятая нужна, но ею отделяется не «слово "когда"», а придаточная часть сложноподчинённого предложения. Я до этого выразился слишком кратко, а имел в виду: если после «сначала» (или перед ним) не стоит ничего, выделяющегося запятыми, как в этом случае, то оно само запятыми не выделяется. По «смыслу»: возможно, герой и обычно наблюдателен, но в этой новой для него ситуации он, похоже, наблюдателен особенно. В частности, он заметил, что молодая скрипачка НЕ улыбнулась зрителям, как другие.

Answer (score 1):

**Я считаю, что** **внутренне**** состояние героя, от лица которого ведется повествование **из** рассказа «Скрипка» очень переменчивое. Если, сначала ему было скучно, то потом мальчик восторженно, **удивленно** слушал игру скрипки. Сначала, когда мама привела его в консерваторию, **первичное** состояние героя было: равнодушие, **незаинтересованность**. Изначально, ему было все равно, куда его ведут: он надел кеды вместо ботинок, не стал чистить свой пиджак. Мальчику **было** все безразлично: куда ему указали, туда он с мамой и сел. Ему не важно, что происходило на сцене. Его внимание ничего не **за**цепляло: «выходили люди, поблескивали очками и водили смычками». Он воспринимал все равнодушно и беспристрастно. Но потом, когда вышла скрипачка, его состояние резко сменилось. Автор подчеркивает это повтором: «заиграла на скрипке, заиграла на узкой скрипке». Мальчик **чувствовал себя** **очень удивленно****, **он** не понимал, как из **такой** **узкой** скрипки**,** выходили красивые звуки. Он стал **внимательно** слушать музыку. Герой был столь потрясен красивой игрой, что даже не захотел **съесть** мороженное: «**-по мороженному**? Нет-нет **-** я сказал, спасибо». **Вот почему** чувства мальчика во время рассказа сильно менялись.

** Выделенное удалил бы или пересмотрел.

Comment: shampar, дело там не столько в выделенном, сколько в ненаписанном (непонятом?) Но я против того, чтобы кидать человеку текст для списывания. Я за то, чтобы дать ему направление, и пусть переписывает сам.

Comment: А я  очень люблю, когда мне КИДАЮТ  тексты для списывания  (и вообще все прочее)  в готовом виде. Десяток таких образцов от выдающихся  художников слова – и я уже пишу лучше, чем они. А что вы хотите! Особая методика обучения – образцы  уходят в подсознание и формируют мой собственный художественный стиль. Скорость обучения в разы выше.  А современные школьники вообще привыкли к восприятию быстрого потока информации, их медленное обучение утомляет.

Comment: shampar, извините, но правильно —  «НИ о чём».

Comment: @Егор Сальков Надо хоть что-то знать о человеке, который сюда пишет. То, что он необидчивый? Это ни о чём. Поэтому, то малое, что мы можем сделать, лучше делать молча, тем более, не обсуждая меж собою «кто за что», не осуждая и не оценивая ответы по шкале вздор/чепуха: ученого учить — только портить.

Comment: shampar, я что-то не понимаю вашу мысль: кто здесь учёный и кто здесь его, учёного, портит?

Comment: У Вас есть свой опыт. Допустите, что и у других таковой есть. Априори мы не просим советов, не создаём команды, не митингуем и не учим друг друга, тихо помогая третьему неизвестному лицу. Такая картина мира меня устроила бы.

Comment: Как интересно, я только что, за много времени взглянула на полку в книжном шкафу, где стояли стихи Веры Полозковой. Потом подхожу к ноутбуку и открываю этот форум, где неожиданно читаю ее стих "Скрипка"...